# modulate tests, sequentially, with nightwatch.js

Tags: javascript, nightwatch.js

How can I thread functions, to run sequentially, threading on top of each other (or modulate, somehow, to make smaller tests).

For instance, I'm using **nightwatch.js** to test a web application - it requires a series of click functions and event listeners to get through to different screens - it works when I have everything in one large function; but when I try to break it multiple functions, per screen or module for instance; the thread is lost (i.e. it doesn't get past login screen), so alas fails. **Any suggestions how to achieve, or modulate?**

*i.e.*

```
this.TeamPanel = function(browser) {
        browser
        // Start
        Errors.checkForErrors(browser);

        browser.end();
};    

this.postTeamPanel = function(browser) {
        browser
        // I want this function to execute where the previous left off, not start over
        Errors.checkForErrors(browser);

        browser.end();
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should not call `browser.end()` until you want to close your test.

Comment: Thanks, so this worked -- however how would I get these functions to report into browser stack as separate tests?